# Connecting PostgreSQL 9.2.1 with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a blank Spring MVC project, and I've installed Hibernate and the PostgreSQL drivers using Maven.

I'm running short on complete tutorials that show how to connect PostgreSQL with Hibernate.

Any help here?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

This is a hibernate.cfg.xml for posgresql and it will help you with basic hibernate configurations for posgresql.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>



        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>



       <mapping class="org.javabrains.sanjaya.dto.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: This is great, but where do I place this file? In WEB-INF?

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari it should be somewhere in your build path.I think WEB-INF will be fine.I don't have much understanding about web projects,but I feel that WEB-INF is in the build path.

Comment: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect is deprecated.
you should use 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
instead

Comment: For 9.2 and later, you should use `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect` instead.

Comment: is this still valid?

Comment: _WEB-INF_ is a web folder and not necessary existing in a project.

Answer (score 8):

**This is the hibernate.cfg.xml file to connect postgresql 9.5 and this is help to you basic configuration.**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration
>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.waseem.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

Make sure File Location should be under **src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml**

Answer (score 6):

If the project is maven placed it in `src/main/resources`, in the package phase it will copy it in `../WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Answer (score -4):

Yes by using spring-boot with hibernate configuration files we can persist the data to the database.
keep hibernating .cfg.xml in your src/main/resources folder for reading the configurations related to database.

[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / XML as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.